# I don't understand this system of inequalities word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations

I don't get how to come up with the 2nd inequality in the answer explanation (not the $b+f$ inequality). Help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Question and Answer here]

[image: Answer Explanation here]

Comment: If $b + f \le 150$ subtract $b$ from both side.  $b + f -b\le 150 - b$ so $f \le 150 - b$.

Comment: I understand that one but I don't understand the other inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make one cake it is necessary to have $4$ cups of batter and $\frac{7}{2}$ cups of frosting. For two cakes: $8$ and $7$ cups, for three cakes: $12$ and $\frac{21}{2}$ cups, for $n$ cakes: $4n$ and $\frac{7}{2}n$ cups, respectively. So if there are $b=4n$ batters, there must be $f=\frac{7}{2}n$ frosts. Having more frosts than required is also possible, which implies leftover frosts.

Now if there are $b$ batters and $f$ frosts, then  it can be made $n=\frac{b}{4}$ cakes provided there are enough frosts, that is $\frac{f}{\frac72}\ge n$. Now substituting first into second you get:
$$\frac{f}{\frac72}\ge \frac{b}{4}.$$

Comment: Wait, what if you have a number of cups of batter that is not a multiple of 4? E.g. you have 7 cups of batter and since 4 cups = 1 cake, you can't make a fraction of a cake so you'll have 3 cups left over right?

Comment: Vert good point. So which choice of four you can eliminate at once? .....................................Right, $B$.

Comment: ahhhh I see thank you

Answer (score 0):

As the image explains, for every $4$ cups of batter, there must be at least $\frac{7}{2}$ cups of frosting. Now, how can we express that? Well, we divide all the batter into groups of $4$ cups and for each one of those groups, the amount of batter has to be smaller (or at least equal, so we can make a cake) than the amount of frosting. But the amount of batter in those groups is just $\frac{b}{4}$ and the amount of frosting is just $\cfrac{f}{\frac{7}{2}}$. With that in mind one arrives at the inequality mentioned.

Comment: Why does there have to be at least 7/2 cups of frosting for every 4 cups of batter though?

Comment: Because that's the condition to make a cake, as stated in the problem. Quote:  "Each cake is made from $4$ cups of batter and $\frac{7}{2}$ cups of frosting."